# Where is the location of shares stored in Windows Server? (Switching iSCSI disk to VMDK)

Tags: windows-server-2008, iscsi, file-sharing, vmware-vmdk

I have a virtualized Windows Server 2008 with iSCSI volume attached (inside the guest). This disk servers as the main file server data disk with lots of shares, permissions, etc.

I would like to "convert" the guest-attached iSCSI volume to a VMWare VMDK by disconnecting the iSCSI target from the Windows Server and reconnecting it inside the VM host and adding it as a virtual disk back to the guest while of course retaining all the file share information.

My question is the following - would it work if I just disconect the iSCSI disk from the Windows Server, attach a virtual disk (VMDK) and change the drive letter to the one previously used by the iSCSI disk?

Answer (score 2):

The list of shares and the share permissions are stored in the registry. The file and folder ACL's are stored in the MFT.

So would this work? Yes it would work, but probably not by the method you're planning. A better method would be to convert the disk to a VMDK from within the guest, then disconnect the iSCSI target, then attach the VMDK to the guest, then release the iSCSI target LUN to the host for it's use.